# change this img square and responsive inside the card

Tags: html, css

It turns out that my img is in rounded corners.. i need them to be in square shape.. is there a problem with my css? This is what it looks like..

[image]

Thanks it will help me a lot!

This is my img css:

```
 .img-wrap {
      position: relative;
      width: 250px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 0px;
    }

     .img-wrap__img {
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       border-radius: 0px;
     }
```

and this is my card layout:

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="thumb">
                     <div class="caption card card-default">
                        <div class="img-wrap">
                          <img src="user_images/<?php echo $row['userPic'] ?>" alt="Card image" class="img-wrap__img" height="100">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Extra div added to enable alignment at bottom -->
                        <div class="excludingImage">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text" style="color:#00873a"><b><?php echo $cartname ?></b></p>
                            <p class="card-text" style="color:#e81b30"><strike style="color:#aaa">₱<?php echo $orig ?>.00</strike> ₱<?php echo $cartprice ?>.00</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="card-footer text-center">
                            <a href="shopview.php?prod=<?php echo $cartname ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-pink btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> View Product </button></a></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.caption -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.thumbnail -->
                  </div>
```

Hope you understand my explanation

Comment: Either there's some css that that overrides `border-radius`, or images are rounded in the first place. You can use _inspect element_ in developer console th check which styles are applied to your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `!important` will help you solve your problem, but my advise **don't use it** , important rule overrides that particular property.

here is a link to help you when to use it https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Like fin1x pointed you must have overridden the border-radius property.
check your css and see where else you might have potentially used it.

```
.img-wrap {
      position: relative;
      width: 250px;
      height: 150px;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 0px; !important
    }

     .img-wrap__img {
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       border-radius: 0px; !important
     }
```

Comment: Thanks!! it helped me a lot :) WORKSS